# Trying to find columns with differences between two sheets that match on one column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have hunted all over the internet, tried all sorts of nested variations involving filtering, matching and not matching, arrayforumulas, countifs, ad infinitem, and this just seems to elude me.

I routinely import a spreadsheet from our student Registry with the latest student data. In the same spreadsheet, I have another sheet where I regularly pull student data and custom metadata from our Google Workspace directory. The sheets have the same columns in the same order. I have a filter and match function that compares the two sheets and looks for student IDs in the Registry sheet that aren't in the Directory sheet, and returns those rows from the Registry to an "Accounts to Add" sheet.

I would like now to find the right combination of Google Sheets functions to compare the two sheets, finding rows with matching student IDs ***but with different values in any of the other columns***. Rows meeting this criteria would be output from the Registry sheet to an "Accounts to Edit" sheet.

In my examples, data in the [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ2J8.png) sheet comes from Google Workspace and ["SIS" (Student Information System)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBezj.png) comes from my import of data from the Registrar's office. In this example there are three rows that match on the Student ID column. Since the first row is exactly the same in both sheets, it needs to be ommitted from the output. In the second row the student's home town changed from Mexico City to Guadalajara. The third student changed her last name when she got married. Hence, the formula(s) would output rows 2 and 3 from the SIS sheet into ["Accounts to Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qotv.png).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this formula:

```
=if(OR(
Directory!C2<>SIS!B2,
Directory!D2<>SIS!C2,
Directory!E2<>SIS!D2,
Directory!F2<>SIS!E2,
Directory!G2<>SIS!F2,
Directory!H2<>SIS!G2,
Directory!I2<>SIS!I2,
Directory!J2<>SIS!J2,
Directory!K2<>SIS!K2
), query(SIS!2:2), "")
```

This formula compares each cell on two rows. If one of them is not the same, it outputs the whole row from "SIS" sheet. If the row is the same, it outputs blank row.

The columns in your screenshots have the same data but they are not in the same positions. For example, on first screenshot "Surname" is a C column and on second it's B. That's why I'm comparing C2 to B2, D2 to C2, etc.
This formula assumes that the data is sorted in the same way in both sheets. As if, student on row 14 in Directory is the same as on row 14 in SIS.

To use it paste it to "Accounts to Edit" in cell A2 and drag it down to the bottom of the sheet. After, create a filter on the sheet and filter out blanks on any of the columns. At this point, it should display all rows with differences. Although, if you update the data in either of the sheets, you will need to refilter it again.

This is not the most elegant solution, but it should work.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Compared to what I've tried, this is extremely elegant. Thanks for catching the fact that the columns aren't in the same positions. I would have caught that eventually, because I'm doing all sorts of things that depend on that arrangement. Anyway, I'll give this a try and let you know. THANKS!!!